# UISwitch to determine what segue to go to

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying make a button that decides what segue to take, depending on if a UISwitch is on or off. Here's my code for the button:

```
- (IBAction)next:(id)sender {

    if (_switch1) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue1" sender:self];
    }
    else if (_switch2) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue2" sender:self];
    }

}
```

So I have 2 switches, called Switch1 and Switch2. When the next button is pressed, I want it to see what switch is on, and then take the user to the appropriate segue.

My problem is the app crashes every time I press the next button.

**EDIT:**
The error I get is:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<IsStudyingViewController 0x15cd7c180> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key back.'`

'IsStudyingViewController' is the name of the file this code is in.

I also get this error whether it's "_switch1" or "_switch1.isOn" or "self.switch1.isOn".

Comment: Please show the exception/crash message, but for a start, if `_switch1` and `_switch2` are `UISwitch` instances you should use `_switch1.isOn` (or even better `self.switch1.isOn`)

Comment: This seems to be an issue with the .xib outlets. Delete all outlets from .xib for `IsStudyingViewController`  and reset them. Even actions for the buttons

Comment: In your scene you have a reference to an IBOutlet "back", but this outlet isn't implemented in your class file

Comment: @Paulw11 I do have an IBAction for a button called "back" which takes the user to the segue "goBack", apart from that theres no other "back".

Comment: An `IBAction` is not an `IBOutlet`.  Your scene refers to an `IBOutlet` called `back`.  If you right-click on the Storyboard you can select "open as...source code" and check the raw text

Comment: Ah yes I found it. Thanks once again @Paulw11 It works!